# Question: Source and Target destination analytical problem SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

Sql table consist of three columns Cust_id,source destination and target destination.
like

```
Cust_id      Source Destination      Target destination
1               Delhi                  Noida
1               Gurgaon                Agra 
1               Agra                   Gurugram
```

Similarly multiple Id's are there. We have to fetch 2 records in total. One with person only went from source destination to target destination and no comeback.The other record will be the one out of the 2 record where the customer went from source destination to target destination and come back from target to source.

Expected output:

```
Cust_id      Source Destination      Target destination
1               Delhi                  Noida
1               Gurgaon                Agra
```

Could anyone post the optimized solution?

Comment: Could you share with us what you have tried so far please

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm . . . This is tricky.  A self-join will bring in the additional target.  But you also want to filter the data.  One method is:

```
select ts.cust_id, ts.source, coalesce(tt.target, ts.target)
from t ts left join
     t tt
     on ts.cust_id = tt.cust_id and ts.source = tt.target
where not exists (select 1
                  from t tt
                  where tt.source = ts.target
                 );
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=88e16a9c4ce1ca4bbdb8c92cdf2112b2) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Gordan. However, with this it is extracting only one record.Delhi to Noida. Could you please provide the copy of your book in pdf format.

Comment: @RajatAnand . . . (1) The book is available to be purchased, but thank you for thinking that authors should not be paid for their work.  (2) I provided a db<>fiddle to show that this code does work.